# How to split a table into two in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL that has data that looks like this:

| ID | Date | Name | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014/7/6 | john | M | 33 |
| 2 | 2015/2/12 | mike | M | 44 |
| 3 | 2001/2/9 | emily | F | 57 |
| . |  |  |  |  |
| . |  |  |  |  |
| . |  |  |  |  |
| 500 | 2017/11/22 | jasmine | F | 20 |

I want to take the bottom 200 rows and make them a new table. How can I do that?

Comment: Duplicate your table then use ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 200 to get the last 200 rows to insert into your new table.

Comment: Why do you want two tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `newTable`
SELECT * FROM `oldTable` 
WHERE ID > 300;
```

Assuming that your bottom 200 rows means when rows are sorted by ID's